# what is zookeeper port and its usage?

Tags: java, neo4j, distributed-computing, apache-zookeeper, voltdb

I am quite new for zookeeper port through which I am coming across from past few days.
I introduced with **zookeeper port** keyword at two occasion:

- while configuring neo4j db cluster ([link](http://lists.neo4j.org/pipermail/user/2011-August/011451.html)) and
- while running compiled voltdb catalog ([link](http://voltdb.com/docs/UsingVoltDB/clivoltdb.php)) (See Network Configuration Arguments)

Then, I came across [Apache Zookeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/), (which I guess is related to distributed application, I am a newbie in distributed application as well). hence question came in my mind:

1. is there any implementation of apache zookeeper in above 2 scenarios ?
2. What exactly this zookeeper port do internally ?

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Zookeeper is used in distributed applications mainly for configuration management and high availability operations. Zookeeper does this by a Master-Slave architecture. Neo4j and VoltDb might be using zookeeper for this purpose

Coming to the ports understanding :
suppose u have 3 servers for zookeepers ... You need to mention in configuration as

```
clientPort=2181
server.1=zookeeper1:2888:3888
server.2=zookeeper2:2888:3888
server.3=zookeeper3:2888:3888
```

Out of these one server will be the master and rest all will be slaves.If any server goes OFF then zookeeper elects leader automatically .

> Servers listen on three ports: 2181 for client connections; 2888 for
>   follower connections, if they are the leader; and 3888 for other
>   server connections during the leader election phase .

Comment: as per your this line `server.1=zookeeper1:2888:3888` is concern, did you mean that hostname is zookeeper ? because above configuration is present in neo4j coord.cfg file..

Comment: Yes zookeeper1(zookeeper2,zookeeper3) refers to HostName