# Adding new server in zookeeper

Tags: apache, apache-zookeeper

I am currently working with replicated servers in the same machine..for instance I am now working with 3 servers ...Now I want to add 2 more server ...How to add it dynamically
this is my zoo.cfg file

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=F:\zookeeper
clientPort=2182
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=localhost:2888:3888
server.2=localhost:2889:3889
server.3=localhost:2890:3890
```

Now I want to add two more servers dynamically

Comment: I have deleted my answer as that is the only way which I know but its not based dynamically.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/miketheman/6057930

Answer (score 1):

Since version 3.5.0, Zookeeper has a Dynamic Reconfiguration feature which allows servers to be added or removed and the entire process is orchestrated via Zookeeper itself. See https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.3-beta/zookeeperReconfig.html. From my experience, reconfiguring an ensemble on version 3.4.6 can get very strange.

Answer (score 0):

server.4=localhost:2891:3891

server.5=localhost:2892:3892

Add above lines to your cfg file .

For details check :  ..[what is zookeeper port and its usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168541/what-is-zookeeper-port-and-its-usage/18186224#18186224)

Comment: ...I want to add it dynamically..not editing the zoo.cfg file..Is there any way?@Sandeep Das

Comment: With version 3.5.0 and up, you can add it dynamically.     [See the docs](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperReconfig.html)

`reconfig -add server.5=125.23.63.23:1234:1235;1236`