# zookeeper colony ：connection refused :Cannot open channel to 3 at election address /192.168.10.129:3883

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I use centos6,zookeeper3.4.6,Pseudo distributed cluster. it happens connection refused :Cannot open channel to 3 at election address /192.168.10.129:3883
now the config as follows;
zookeep1/data/myid:1
zookeep2/data/myid:2
zookeep3/data/myid:3

zookeep1/zoo.cfg:
/home/lwj/solrcloud/zookeep1/data/
clientPort=2181
server.1=127.0.0.1:2881:3881
server.2=127.0.0.1:2882:3882
server.3=127.0.0.1:2883:3883

zookeep2/zoo.cfg:
/home/lwj/solrcloud/zookeep2/data/
clientPort=2182
server.1=127.0.0.1:2881:3881
server.2=127.0.0.1:2882:3882
server.3=127.0.0.1:2883:3883

zookeep3/zoo.cfg:
/home/lwj/solrcloud/zookeep3/data/
clientPort=2183
server.1=127.0.0.1:2881:3881
server.2=127.0.0.1:2882:3882
server.3=127.0.0.1:2883:3883

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgXd9.png)

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: this zookeeper cluster start with exception 。I cannot find the problem。

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are running 3 instances of Zookeeper in the same host. Check the state of the port 3882 in your host .`netstat -a | grep 3882`

Clear the iptables in the host to free ports `service iptables clear`

Also, its good practice to give  IP `192.168.10.129` rather than the localhost(127.0.0.1) in the configuration .

For zookeeper port details Look :

[what is zookeeper port and its usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168541/what-is-zookeeper-port-and-its-usage/18186224#18186224)